# ADO.NET Entity Framework and WCF in .NET 3.5 Framework

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework

In my new project I am asked to use ADO.NET Entity framework and WCF Services. I am quite to new to this but when I studied and worked on few samples I found idea behind using Entity framework entities as WCF contract is pretty confusing.
So wanted to know what is the general opinion on this. I studied about Persistence Ignorance as well and bit about POCO support in 4.0 version but somehow we can't move to 4.0 for this project.
IS PI possible in 3.5 as well ? Are there any samples available which I can study. I tried implementing POCO adapter but the sample available on Codeplex was too confusing to implement in a web application.

My overall point is to decouple the DataContracts and the Entities created by the Entity Framework. how is that possible or using Ado.net Entities as Contract is the only option in 3.5.

Comment: You really want to use v4.0 and not the previous version (with 3.5 SP 1).  I'm pretty sure EFv1 doesn't support POCO entities, but I can guarantee a world of pain with EFv1 and WCF.

Comment: @RobS, WCF Data Services are supported in 3.5. They are not "a world of pain." They're incredibly easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out this [EF Poco Adapter](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFPocoAdapter) for Entity Framework v1.0.  It specifically applies Persistence Ignorance for Entity Framework entities.  As for using it with WCF, you may or may not be able to couple it with WCF Data Services, I haven't explored this.

Actually, you could expose the POCO entities via WCF data contracts:

> "Entity Framework V1 programming
>   interfaces are wrapped with
>   corresponding APIs that work with POCO
>   objects and do necessary translation
>   between POCO and Persistence-Aware
>   objects."

So all you need to do is wire up your data access on the service side and (apparently) the EF Adapter will handle mapping to the persistence aware versions for you.

Comment: I tried implementing POCO Adapter but somehow couldn't implement it for a web application, got all sorts of error :(. I have no real idea about WCF data services but will look in to that as well.

Comment: Hi Kunal.  I'd try using the POCO objects in the data contract definition and then use the Adapter to map them to the actual EF types in your web service implementation (or another tier).  Sorry, I haven't use this adapter before, I upgraded to v4 for the new POCO support before it became an issue

Comment: Have you actually tried this? You're worried about Data Services being painful and you're suggesting the EF 1 POCO Adapter?!?

Comment: There is one more thing for which I have a doubt, somewhere in the stack overflow I read that there are interoperability issues if Entity framework entities are used as WCF Data Contracts. Is that a case really? I doubt, since only those properties are exposed and sent across wire which are marked as Data Member, I see no interoperability issue here.

Answer (score -3):

[You can use WCF Data Services in .NET 3.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20130531041440/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/01/27/data-services-update-for-net-3-5-sp1-available-for-download.aspx).

Comment: No offense meant Craig, but I don't think this answer does much to address the OPs question.  How does WCF Data Services help in Persistence Ignorance and decoupling Contracts/Entities/Contexts?

Comment: @RobS, he asked how to use EF entities in a WCF service. It seems to me that he sees POCOs as a means to this end. But it isn't the only means. WCF Data Services are easy. POCOs in EF 1 are painful (but not in EF 4).